# Failure to load existing library

Tags: linux, linker, filesystems, shared-libraries

I'm trying to explain a complex problem, so bear with me.

Say I have these files

```
/path/build/
/path/build/liba.so
/path/build/liba.so.3 -> liba.so
/path/build/libtest.so
```

I even have set `PATH=/path/build:...` (where `...` is my normal `$PATH`).

At some point `libtest.so` will load `liba.so.3` at runtime.

However, `liba.so.3` doesn't seem to exist when running code that (successfully) loads `libtest.so`, and when I ask `ldd` for help, I get this:

```
$ ldd /path/build/libtest.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff24fff000)
liba.so.3 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8fea222000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8fe9f9e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8fe9d88000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8fe9b6a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8fe97c9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8fea767000)
```

(note the second output line)

How can I figure out what's going wrong? The library is clearly there, but the loader claims it's not.

Comment: is /path/build on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  The linux dynamic loader looks here for libraries on Linux, after the default locations.

Comment: @keith Please change that comment into an answer, and I will accept the guts out of you! Oh boy, I'm going to sit down in a corner for 5 minutes and let the shame kick in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is /path/build on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH? The linux dynamic loader looks here for libraries on Linux, after the default locations